# Getting error when I attempt to debug an ASP.NET 3.5 web site using Visual Studio 8

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I'm getting the following error when I attempt to debug a web site I've created with Visual Studio 8, and ASP.NET 3.5 Framework.

Anyone know how I can fix this issue?

Thanks,
Greg

...

> Auto-attach to process '[8036] aspnet_wp.exe' on machine 'S418-B-XA2A' failed. Check for one of the following.
>
> 1. The application you are trying to debug uses a version of the Microsoft .NET Framework that is not supported by the debugger.
> 2. The debugger has made an incorrect assumption about the Microsoft .NET Framework version your application is going to use.
> 3. The Microsoft .NET Framework version specified by you for debugging is incorrect.
>
> Please see the Visual Studio .NET debugger documentation for correctly specifying the Microsoft .NET Framework version your application is going to use for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I think your IDE is defaulting to a different .NET framework version, you need to set it properly in the debugger, see for example : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241897(v=VS.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241897%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Just to add on this, if you are using 64 bit system, the registry key is under Wow6432